# Override render function of shapes

Tags: javascript, oop, fabricjs

I am trying to override render function of several shapes in Fabric.js.

The reason is that I don't want to create objects which are too small e.g. smaller than 10px width and height.
The implementation is that the user creates shapes on mouse dragging: 
`mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup => and the shape is created.`

On mouse down, we start initializing the shape with 1px.
This way on every click on the canvas we create very small objects (several pixels in dimension)
It is possible to increase this size to 20px and the behavior will be to create a small shape on every click, but that is not wanted effect also.

How could I override the render function in order to create shapes which are with dimensions bigger than 10px in width and height and if smaller no shape to be created or rendered at all?

All render functions are with different interface and logic depending on the shape they render but also suppose that if that is achievable the implementation will be similar for all.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `object:added` event to check the size of objects at creation and then remove/resize them as needed?

Comment: Well, I tried to play "smart" and override / extend the default behavior of Fabric. But after I realized that a lot of changes are involved made the same as you suggest here.